# How to add multiple colors to an array

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to add multiple colors to an array in an HTML5 canvas animation. I am using an if statement to add 3 different colors based on the array index, but the only color showing up is the "else" color (orange). Below is the code.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas        = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    context       = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    w             = window.innerWidth,
    h             = window.innerHeight,
    total         = 100,
    gumballs      = [];
    canvas.width  = w;
    canvas.height = h;

    for(var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        gumballs.push({
            x: Math.random()* w,
            y: Math.random()* h,
            r: Math.random()* 4+3,
            d: Math.random()*total
        })
    }   

    function draw() {
        context.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
        context.beginPath();
        for(var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            var s = gumballs[i];
            if(s % 3 === 0){
                context.fillStyle = 'blue';
            } else if (s % 4 === 0) {
                context.fillStyle = 'red';
            } else {
                context.fillStyle = "orange";
            }
            context.moveTo(s.x, s.y);
            context.arc(s.x, s.y, s.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        } 
        context.fill();
        update();
    }

    function update() {
        for(var i = 0;  i < total; i++) {
            var s = gumballs[i];
            s.y +=  8;
            if(s.x > w + 10 || s.x < - 10 || s.y > h) {
                gumballs[i] = {x: Math.random()*w, y: 0, r: s.r, d: s.d};                   
            }
        }
    }
    setInterval(draw, 30);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do .fill for each gumball rather than one .fill at the end:

```
function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    for(var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        var s = gumballs[i];
        if((i%3) == 0){
            context.fillStyle = 'blue';
        } else if ((i%4) == 0) {
            context.fillStyle = 'red';
        } else {
            context.fillStyle = "orange";
        }
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(s.x, s.y);
        context.arc(s.x, s.y, s.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        context.fill();
    } 
    update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like gumballs[i] will always be an object - {x, y, r, d} - and so s % 3 and s % 4 will be NaN, causing the code to fall to the else clause.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another way I can add multiple colors to the array?

Answer (score 0):

You state you want to set color based on array index so your `if` should be checking index, not the array element at that index

Try changing:

```
if(s % 3 === 0){
```

To:

```
if(i % 3 === 0){
```

Same for other `if`

Comment: I just tried that and they all turned blue, which was the first if statement. But it still isn't adding multiple colors.